# Show validation message below the input (IE9 and IE7)

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc, internet-explorer-7, internet-explorer-9

I'm using razor to render a textbox and its validation message:

```
     @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Login, new { maxlength = "20"})
     @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Login)
```

I need to show the validation message below the element, and I need the style works both in IE9 and IE7. If I use `<br />`, IE 7 displays a blank line below and then the message, and IE 9 shows the message correctly below the input without any space.

Is there a way I can do this for the two browsers? I would like to know the most appropriated way to do this kind of stuff as well.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

```
<div>
     @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Login, new { maxlength = "20"})
</div>
<div>
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Login)
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may be up against CSS differences between IE7 and IE9. Use the development tools to examine the validation message and see if you can change the CSS that is applied to validation errors. You can change them to get the UI to behave the same in both browsers.